# Showing that a parametric curve has two tangent lines

Tags: calculus

Question:
Show that the curve x = 4 cos(t), y = 5 sin(t) cos(t)
has two tangents at (0, 0) and find their equations. (Enter your answers as a comma-separated list.)

I know that dx/dt = -4sin(t), dy/dt = 5cos(2t), and that at the point (0,0) that cos(t) = 0 which only occurs at odd multiples of pi/2.

I do not understand the remaining blanks in the picture. Please help me find and explain them. [image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77EO6.png)

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: The first red box is :$\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{3\pi}{2}$ the rest than follows, since I hope you can differentiate

Comment: Do you really think that including "(Enter your answers as a comma-separated list.)" is pertinent to copy here ?

Comment: This curve belongs to the family of "Lissajous curves".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**First blank.** The question is asking for all the values of $t$ that satisfies $\cos t=0$ such that $t\in[\,0,2\pi)$. As you have answered in the previous blank, these values occur at odd multiples of $\frac{\pi}{2}$, but as you may notice only $t=\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $t=\frac{3\pi}{2}$ satisfy both conditions.
**Second, third and fourth blanks.** Here, "these values" refer to the values in the first blank, so the smallest is $\frac{\pi}{2}$. Using $\frac{dx}{dt}=-4\sin t$ and $\frac{dy}{dt}=5\cos 2t$ we have
$$\left.\frac{dx}{dt}\right|_{t=\pi/2}=-4\sin\frac{\pi}{2}=-4$$
and
$$\left.\frac{dy}{dt}\right|_{t=\pi/2}=5\cos\left(2\cdot\frac{\pi}{2}\right)=-5.$$
Because $\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{dy/dt}{dx/dt}$, we can substitute in the above values to get
$$\left.\frac{dy}{dx}\right|_{t=\pi/2}=\frac{-5}{-4}=\frac{5}{4}.$$
**Fifth, sixth and seventh blanks.** This is similar to what we did for the second to fourth blanks, but with the largest value from the first blank instead of the smallest one, which is $\frac{3\pi}{2}$. First we compute the $x$- and $y$-derivatives at this value:
$$\left.\frac{dx}{dt}\right|_{t=3\pi/2}=-4\sin\frac{3\pi}{2}=4$$
$$\left.\frac{dy}{dt}\right|_{t=3\pi/2}=5\cos\left(2\cdot\frac{3\pi}{2}\right)=-5$$
and so
$$\left.\frac{dy}{dx}\right|_{t=3\pi/2}=-\frac{5}{4}.$$